# Unable to download file in laravel ajax on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

When I am trying to use the download button to download file in laravel ajax, it is not working properly and I am not able to download file.

Below is my code:

```
<button type="button" request_id="'.$data->id.'" class="btn btn-success download_request_btn" > Download </button>';
```

Controller:

```
public function downloadReport(Request $request)
    {
        $request_id = $request->request_id;
        $downloadReport = Upload::where('id', $request_id)->first();
        $upload_report = $downloadReport->upload_report;
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
            'Content-Type: application/docx',
          );
        $url= url('storage/documents/request/'. $upload_report);
        return response()->download($url);
    }
```

Ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '.download_request_btn', function(){
            var request_id = $(this).attr('request_id');
           console.log(request_id);
           var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('request_id',request_id);
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: site_url+"/DownloadAjax",
                data: formData,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success: function (res) {

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I see you retrieve the data, does it actually retrieve it but you need to know the next steps to do in the success callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to pseudo-code it up with trusting your data is coming back as desired I think you need to trigger the download in your success callback with a variation of the following (may need to adjust to your need):

```
$(document).on('click', '.download_request_btn', function(){
    var request_id = $(this).attr('request_id');
    console.log(request_id);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('request_id',request_id);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: site_url+"/DownloadAjax",
        data: formData,
        contentType:false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (res) {
            const data = res;
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', data);
            link.setAttribute('download', 'yourfilename.extensionType'); // Need to modify filename ...
            link.click();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass header to force file type and download

```php
$file_path = storage_path('documents/request/'. $upload_report);
$headers = array('Content-Type'=> 'application/pdf');
return \Response::download($file_path, 'file.pdf', $headers);
```

here you need to add header based on your file type

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads

Comment: file is downloading but with name image.html

Comment: `($file_path, 'file.pdf', $headers)`  here 2nd parameter is name it should be correct

Comment: $image_url= url('storage/documents/request/');$upload_report = $downloadReport->upload_report;
  return \Response::download($image_url, $upload_report, $headers);

Comment: Still getting image.html

Comment: it is image or pdf?

Comment: we have to download pdf as well as image too

Comment: so based on that you need to change headers and `$upload_report` this variable should contain file extention

Answer (score -1):

```
 if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists(($exportDir.'/'.$fileName))) {
            $data = route('yourdownloadCSV',['nameFile' => $fileName]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 1,
            'data'   => $data,
            'message'=> trans('messages.item_upload_shop_ok'),
        ]);

public function yourdownloadCSV($nameFile) {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '9072M');
        ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
        set_time_limit(10*60);

        $fullFolderZipFile  = public_path().'/export/'.date('ym');
        $filePath           = $fullFolderZipFile.'/'.$nameFile;
        $nameDownload       = "test";

        if(file_exists($filePath)) {
            $byteS  = filesize($filePath);
            $mb     = number_format($byteS / 1048576, 2) ;
            if($mb>10){
                $filePathZip= ZipUtil::generateZipFromFile($filePath,$fullFolderZipFile,$nameFile);
                $nameDownload .=".zip";
            }else{
                $filePathZip = $filePath;
                $nameDownload .=".".pathinfo($nameFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            }

            $mimeType = File::mimeType($filePathZip);
            return response()->download($filePathZip,$nameDownload,[
                'Content-Type' => $mimeType,
                'Content-Encoding' => 'Shift-JIS'
            ])->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).