# Unable to download file as PDF from browser when using LARAVEL AJAX

Tags: laravel, pdf, download, filenames

I am using this ajax to pass my data from one view to pdf view in laravel. I am able to get data in the pdf preview but it unable to download from browser

```
                    
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url:"{{ route('monthlybilling.monthlybill') }}",
                    type:"GET",
                    //dataType:"json",
                    data:{
                        site:site, 
                        startdate:startdate,
                        },
                        xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob' // to avoid binary data being mangled on charset conversion
                },
                success: function(blob, status, xhr) {
                
                    // check for a filename
                    var filename = "";
                    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
                        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                        if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
                    }

                    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
                        // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
                    } else {
                        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                        if (filename) {
                            // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
                            var a = document.createElement("a");
                            // safari doesn't support this yet
                            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                            } else {
                                a.href = downloadUrl;
                                a.download = filename;
                                document.body.appendChild(a);
                                a.click();
                            }
                        } else {
                            window.location.href = downloadUrl;
                        }

                        // setTimeout(function() {
                        //     URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
                        // }, 100); // cleanup
                    }
```

Here is my controller:  [

```
 $data = DB::table('weekly_data')
                ->where('site', $request->site)
                ->whereBetween('report_date',[$request->startdate,$request->enddate])
                ->get();
        
        $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('weeklypdf', compact('data'));
        $pdf ->setPaper('a4','landscape');
        return $pdf->stream('weeklyBillingReport.pdf');
```

Also, it unable to save the file name automatically like "weeklyBillingReport.pdf"
[image]

When I clicks 'SAVE', it shows "Failed - Network Error"

[image]

Comment: This is more of a package issue than Laravel. Try to use this and see if it works.
 `return $pdf->download('weeklyBillingReport.pdf');`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64747187/unable-to-download-file-in-laravel-ajax-on-button-click/64747248#64747248

Comment: @RianZaman ```return $pdf->download('weeklyBillingReport.pdf');``` not works

Comment: @KamleshPaul Is this use in controller??

Comment: @nunu it have both answer you can check

Comment: What package are you using to make pdf?

Comment: @RianZaman I'm using dompdf to create pdf. The ajax i used enable to pass data to pdf view but now i suspect there is some problem in this ajax which make it unable to download from browser & unable to name the filename

Comment: @KamleshPaul  tried this ``` const data = res;
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', data);
            link.setAttribute('download', 'yourfilename.extensionType'); // Need to modify filename ...
            link.click(); 
```
it unable to download and show "Failed - Server problem"


tried this ```$file_path = storage_path('documents/request/'. $upload_report);
$headers = array('Content-Type'=> 'application/pdf');
return \Response::download($file_path, 'file.pdf', $headers);```
it shows  error 500

Comment: @nunu can you show what error ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul jquery.js:10099 GET http://localhost/home/weeklybilling/pdf?site=ACC & startdate=2020-12-15&enddate=2020-12-22&_token=L6yd1HqV3F3NpFfBp0FpFwA0tpQDxtPpFOiiedPf 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution here:

```
   success: function(blob, status, xhr) {
                    var ieEDGE = navigator.userAgent.match('/Edge/g');
                    var ie = navigator.userAgent.match('/.NET/g'); // IE 11+
                    var oldIE = navigator.userAgent.match('/MSIE/g');

                    if (ie || oldIE || ieEDGE) {
                        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                    } else {
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i did that :

```
 $license = license::findOrFail($id);
    $data = [
        'license' => $license,
        'user' => Auth::user(),
        'labels' => LicValues::where('license_id', $id)->get()
    ];
    return PDF::loadView('print', $data)->download('print.pdf');
```

i have one blade named print and i pass $data to that and finally its downloaded.

and its in ajax request also